# Upgrade password hash from md5 to bcrypt

Tags: hash, passwords, md5, bcrypt

Its been discussed here before, but there seems to be no conclusion.

Ideally, don't want to maintain state (upgraded/not upgraded) in the database etc. so, here is what I'm thinking:

bcrypt the MD5'd password, and use "username + something else" as a salt.

1. Does this scheme make any sense?
2. Also, in general is it a good idea to use the username as a part of the salt? I read somewhere that adding a different salt to each hash makes it more secure. Is that correct (especially in context of bcrypt)?

Comment: Please explain the downvote

Comment: This would be a better fit on [security.se] but check their help centre before you post.

Comment: Check out `password_hash()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @Tim I did - and I want to know if password_hash(MD5'd password + username + "fixed random string") is a good idea?

Comment: @user3714828 `password_hash()` creates its own salt, so you don't have to bother with the username.

Comment: @Tim but would that introduce any extra entropy in the system? Adding an extra string definitely does that

Comment: @user3714828 yes, adding extra entropy is what makes salting useful. It means the would be hacker has to deal with all that extra entropy in his attempt to hack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely it is a good idea to switch to a more secure hash algorithm. There is a function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) you can use for creating a BCrypt hash:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

From your answer i guess that you used an unsalted MD5 value, so double hashing can be a good solution here. Just pass the MD5 hash to the password_hash() function, it will generate a safe salt on its own.

```
// Migrating the old MD5 hashes to MD5-BCrypt
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($existingMd5Hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

For verification first [check for a double hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/103403/8343), and then verify the password accordingly.

```
if (checkIfDoubleHash($existingHashFromDb))
{
  $isPasswordCorrect = password_verify(MD5($password), $existingHashFromDb);

  // Update database with pure BCrypt hash
  if ($isPasswordCorrect)
    $hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
else
{
  $isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb)
}
```

The stored hashes can be recognized by the leading $ or by a separate db field, a BCrypt hash for example always starts with a $ character, an MD5 hash does not.

A salt should **not** be derrived from other parameters and it should be unique per password. The password_hash() function will take care of this. Since a rainbowtable must be built fore each salt, an attacker would have to build a rainbowtable for each password. For more information you can have a look at my tutorial about [secure password storing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).